# ALTER A TABLE - table names vary and are stored in a database

Tags: mysql

We have database tables created by a user and need to add columns to all database tables within the database that match a certain type.

We want to add externalLinkURL column to these tables

```
ADD COLUMN `isExternalLink` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER visibility;
```

We can get the table names from X_metaTable.tableName (SELECT tableName from X_metaTablename;)

Any pointers on writing this query. I've tried

```
ALTER TABLE (
   SELECT tableName FROM X_metaTablename)
ADD COLUMN `isExternalLink` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL  AFTER visibility,
```

Comment: "We have database tables created by a user" = Uh-oh. Relational databases are not designed for this at all. You'll need to wreck around with stored procedures, at best, or use a scripting language to bridge the gap here. `ALTER TABLE` is not intended to be used this way, and does not support dynamic data like that.

Comment: You'll probably can write some Dynamic SQL to assemble the `ALTER TABLE` statements, and then run them. Or... you can write a query to generate all the `ALTER TABLE` statements into an output script for review. Once you verify it, you can load it and run it.